# when i input the image path,i get a syntax error

Tags: python, image, path, syntax-error

```
#import module
import ...
#import path

IMAGE_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\input"))
IMAGE_MASK_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\mask"))
#preprocessing_augmentation
IMAGE_INITIAL_PATH = open(r"C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\augmentation")
IMAGE_AUGMENTATED_PATH = open(r"C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\rotated")
Data_Gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=180)
IMG_AUG = Data_Gen.flow_from_directory(IMAGE_INITIAL_PATH, batch_size=1
                                  , save_to_dir=IMAGE_AUGMENTATED_PATH,
                                   save_prefix='Aug', target_size=(192,192))

for i in range(9):
    IMG_AUG.next()

def Pre_Process_Augmentation(Path_Images):

Images_List = glob.glob(Path_Images)
Figure = plt.figure()

for i in range (9):
    Images_A = Image.open(Images_List[i])
    Sub_Image_Show = Figure.add_subplot(331 + i)
    Sub_Image_Show.imshow(Images_A)
plt.show()
return Figure
```

### i want to image augmentation but when i input IMAGE-MASK-PATH i get a syntax error,how can i solve them and what is wrong?

---

---

Comment: That line is missing a closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: There's likely a missing parentheses on an earlier line as well, given the error message. The improved error messages in Python 3.11 would indicate the unclosed `(` specifically, and earlier Pythons won't "catch" the error until a line *after* the unclosed `(`.

Comment: Check your parentheses on line 15 (or possibly earlier) as well.

Comment: After the edit your code has `IMAGE_MASK_PATH` and in your description of the error you say `IMAGE-MASK-PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot the last parenthesis ?

Shouldn't it be like this :

```py
IMAGE_MASK_PATH = open(
   os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\mask")
)
```

Edits :

Here is what you gave me...

```py
IMAGE_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\input")
IMAGE_MASK_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\mask")
Data_Gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=180)
IMG_AUG = Data_Gen.flow_from_directory(IMAGE_INITIAL_PATH, batch_size=1 , save_to_dir=IMAGE_AUGMENTATED_PATH, save_prefix='Aug', target_size=(192,192))
```

You literally lost 2 parenthesis ! Check the differences :

```py
IMAGE_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\input"))
IMAGE_MASK_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\mask"))
Data_Gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=180)
IMG_AUG = Data_Gen.flow_from_directory(IMAGE_INITIAL_PATH, batch_size=1 , save_to_dir=IMAGE_AUGMENTATED_PATH, save_prefix='Aug', target_size=(192,192))
```

Comment: if i put the last parenthesis,it still gives an error

Comment: @mahdisabbasi Can you provide us more code above and below this line please ?

Comment: IMAGE_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\input")
IMAGE_MASK_PATH = open(os.path.join("C:\Users\Mahdis\Desktop\MRI\mask")                                                                                                                                                           Data_Gen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=180) 
IMG_AUG = Data_Gen.flow_from_directory(IMAGE_INITIAL_PATH, batch_size=1
                                      , save_to_dir=IMAGE_AUGMENTATED_PATH,
                                       save_prefix='Aug', target_size=(192,192))

Comment: how can i share all codes with you?

Comment: @mahdisabbasi Put it in the description, underneath your first text